# AWS - Not able to monitor free tier usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, billing

I'm new to AWS and wanted to give it a shot with the free tier offer. I'd like to monitor my usage, especially so I'm aware how many free hours I've left so I don't exceed them. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/tracking-free-tier-usage.html#free-tier-table) (and some Google results) say I can find a table called **Top Free Tier Service by Usage** - but I can't. **The Billing & Cost Management Dashboard**, where it's supposed to be, does not show this table.

My account is eligible for the free usage tier - I paid attention to it while registering and the dashboard also says that. I've created (and already terminated) the following three instances:

- 2 EC2 t2.micro
- 1 Elastic Beanstalk Web Server

They all ran for approx. 10 minutes each.

Does anybody know the reason? Is it just that I have to wait and the data is not in real time or did I screw up something?

I've already done research on my own and was not able to find a solution.

Comment: It might take a little while for the billing data to come through. Can you check after 1-2 days?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yea. It's there now. Thanks

Comment: Please resolve this question @RichardSteinbrecht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John suggested, waiting 1 - 2 days solved the issue.